# Swift Array - use "Contains" of type AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use function `contains` on Array of type `AnyObject`

```
import UIKit

var resultArray: Array<AnyObject> = Array()
resultArray.append(50)
resultArray.append(false)
resultArray.append("Test string")
let found = contains(resultArray, 50)
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'AnyObject -> L' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

[image]

Comment: Don't mix types in an array, it is not a good practice. In this case make 50 a string so all items have a String type.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of `AnyObject`?

Comment: As Zaph said, using AnyObject is not ideal unless you really need to. One example of a purpose for AnyObject is when writing or using an API, fetching some information of which the data type is undetermined by you, the programmer. eg. Parse's framework uses AnyObject as it doesn't know if you are storing a String, Bool, Int etc. You then must convert it as soon as possible.

Comment: @ByronCoetsee, Yes, I am writing an API. And this Array is class variable, used in a Protocol delegate method. Class that implements this delegate method may return any type of object in completion block. This Array of objects may be of some String types or may be some Modal class objects. e.g "User"
Objects at all index would be same i.e; Strings or User. So eventually the Array would be converted into some determined type. But I don't know in advance what type of objects they would be. How can I use it until the type is undetermined?

Comment: @Khawar have a look at my answer and see if that helps. Might not be the most efficient way but it should solve your issue :)

Comment: Your use of Comic Sans is noted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with the comments and other answer; `AnyObject` is not good practice, but if you **really** want to use `AnyObject`, you can treat your array of AnyObjects as an `NSArray` object and then use the function `containsObject()`:

```
if (resultArray as NSArray).containsObject(AnyObjectOfAnyType) {
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: @trevoj, thanks it works. But I am looking for more efficient solution.

Comment: @Khawar More efficient how? You should be able to check for any possible object in this one if statement.

Comment: lol.. you are right. I was trying to get rid of all types starting with `NS` :). If I couldn't find any (I believe), I'll mark you answer as accepted. I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! I cast a lot of my `Array`s to `NSArray` to use the functions that only `NSArray` has.

Comment: It's inefficient in so much as it requires you to stick with `AnyObject`, which means you are giving up on all of Swift's value types and converting everything to NSObjects (and then converting the whole array from an Array itself to an NSArray).  Though I realize you did point this out AnyObject was a bad practice the start of your answer... :)

Comment: If `AnyObject` is not good practice, what else can I use? I don't in advance what type of objects the Array would be filled with.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be using `Any` in this example since you’re holding non-class types – otherwise you’ll be doing implicit conversion to `NSThing`s.

But here’s a non-ObjC-interop way to do it:

```
let found = contains(resultArray) { ($0 as? Int) == 50 }
```

Comment: @Airspeed, thanks for the answer. But it is checking for `Int` only. I am checking `50` just for example. I need a statement that can check any of the types types at runtime.

Comment: I'm really not meaning to be confrontational when I say: you probably don't actually need this kind of "dynamic" behavior at runtime.  I'd suggest posting a question with the context of the actual problem you want to solve – chances are you can do it with compile-time polymorphism (i.e. a generic algorithm) or runtime (i.e. with classes/protocols and dynamic dispatch).  Using AnyObject is pretty grungy from many angles (keeps you stuck in @objc land, inefficient at runtime, type-unsafe etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` keyword to differentiate between types, then use the piece of code by Airspeed Velocity above to do the search... Here's an example that you can modify and add extra types on if need be:

```
if resultArray[0] is String {
    found = contains(resultArray) {
        ($0 as? String) == "hello"
    }
} else if resultArray[0] is Int {
    found = contains(resultArray) {
        ($0 as? Int) == 50
    }
}
```

NOTE: You said your array will contain only 1 type at a time - this is important.

Comment: thanks for answer. But I need a generic check, that can be used with Any type supported by Swift. In your example there are multiple checks. What if Array can contain 10 different types of objects, there would be `10` if statements?

Comment: Oh I thought you meant the whole array will be of one type when you said "Objects at all index would be same i.e; Strings or User"... Evaluating on a per element basis without the use of a for loop, I don't know unfortunately. - the for loop could basically use the code I showed above, but just evaluate each element; although this would not be a good idea for large arrays. As for your question re. 10 if statements, a switch case would be better suited :P